# chart.js 2.7.1 | Updating charts with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm trying to use chart.js on my website. But I have some problems with updating ones.

HTML:

```
  <a href="#" class="date-select" data-chart="dishesChart" data-period="day">day</a>
  <a href="#" class="date-select" data-chart="dishesChart" data-period="week">week</a>
  <a href="#" class="date-select" data-chart="dishesChart" data-period="month">month</a>

  <canvas id="dishesChart" style="width: 100%;"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var dishesChartCanvas = document.getElementById("dishesChart");

var dayDataset = {
   datasets: [{
     data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   }],

   labels: [
     some data array
   ]
};

// here comes same variables for week and month datasets


var dishesChart = new Chart(dishesChartCanvas, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: dayDataset, // default
  options: dishesChartOptions
});
```

The problem is:
This code is working:

```
$('.date-select').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dishesChart.data.datasets[0].data = monthDataset.datasets[0].data;
  dishesChart.data.labels = monthDataset.labels;
  dishesChart.update();
});
```

But this code give **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property**

```
$('.date-select').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var chartname = $(this).data("chart");
  var period = $(this).data("period") + "Dataset";
  chartname.data.datasets[0].data = period.datasets[0].data;
  chartname.data.labels = period.labels;
  chartname.update();
});
```

I'm newbie to JS and jQuery, so let me know what am I doing wrong.

Thank you!

### **UPD: Fixed**

By default data-attribute is string, to convert it to object you should add window[var_name]:

problem:

```
var chartname = $(this).data("chart");
```

solution:

```
var chartname = window[$(this).data("chart")];
```

---

Comment: Pls add your solution as answer in StackOverflow

Comment: @beaver updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var chartname = window[$(this).data("chart")];
```